# How do I make 'n' number of spriteNodes appear inside the screen size and move around inside the screen?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, landscape, skspritenode, skaction

I have coded like below:

```
func spriteCollection(count : Int) -> [SKSpriteNode]{

    var spriteArray = [SKSpriteNode]()

    for _ in 0..<count {

        let sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "node.png")

        //giving random position to sprites, but problem is some sprites are going invisible. How do I make it appear inside the view?

        let x = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height)))

        let y = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width)))

        sprite.position = CGPoint(x: x, y: y)

        spriteArray.append(sprite)

    }

    return spriteArray

}

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    let spriteCollection = spriteCollection(10)

    for sprite in spriteCollection{

        //facing problem here, not sure how to move it inside the view

        let x = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(size.height)))

        let y = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(size.width)))

        let action = SKAction.moveTo(CGPoint(x: x , y: y), duration: 5)

        sprite.runAction(action)

        addChild(sprite)
   }
}
```

The problem I'm facing now is, if I pass count 10 to `spriteCollection`, I can only see 5 or 6 sprites and rest all are hidden. I just want to make all sprites appear inside the screen size and when I perform move action its position should be inside the screen too. I'm working in landscape mode. Could anyone please help me resolve this..

Comment: So check the scene's size and check the spawn coordinates and see if some nodes are off-screen...

Comment: I just printed the positions of nodes as well as view's width and height.  Optional(667.0) <---view's width
Optional(375.0) <--- view's height                                                                   x and y positions of all nodes below
(492.0, 62.0)
(479.0, 67.0)
(189.0, 248.0)
(91.0, 298.0)
(54.0, 214.0)
(490.0, 155.0)
(590.0, 224.0)
(127.0, 122.0)
(328.0, 233.0)
(204.0, 195.0)                                                                                      Looks like every co-ordinates are inside but still some nodes are not visible. What I'm doing wrong

Comment: What is the scene's size? (you are adding nodes to the scene). Scene can have different size than view. By default, scene size is 1024x768 if you are loading it from the .sks file.

Comment: yeah scene size is 1024 X 768,

Comment: Inside your game view controller put something like `scene.size = skView.bounds.size`.

Comment: Great.. It worked.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are running into is the fact that the screen's bounds are oriented to the device when it is in Portrait mode while your view's bounds are based on the screen size when it is in Landscape mode.

One way to solve your issue would be to reverse your x and y calculations when you are working in "screen space"

```
// Note how width and height appear to be "backward" here.  That's because the screen
// coordinates are defined by the portrait orientation of the device,
// but the view will eventually be in a landscape orientation

let x = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width)))
let y = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height)))
```

But I think a better idea would be to wait to move your sprites into their initial positions until after the view has been created and then position them randomly based on the **view's** bounds and not the **screen's** bounds

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, if you can see in my code I have interchanged the width and height. For x position I'm considering height and vice versa. But still I'm facing the issue. and also I tried considering the view bounds instead of screen's, But still no luck. Do you have any other suggestions to reslove this?

Comment: I just printed the positions of nodes as well as view's width and height.  Optional(667.0)view's width
Optional(375.0)view's height
(492.0, 62.0)
(479.0, 67.0)
(189.0, 248.0)
(91.0, 298.0)
(54.0, 214.0)
(490.0, 155.0)
(590.0, 224.0)
(127.0, 122.0)
(328.0, 233.0)
(204.0, 195.0)